# Why isn't the client secret needed for OAuth from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

Good news is that I followed the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) on accessing Google Drive REST API over Javascript and it worked. However, `client_id` but **not** `client_secret` is used in the code.

```
/**
* Check if current user has authorized this application.
*/
function checkAuth() {
 gapi.auth.authorize(
   {
     'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
     'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
     'immediate': true
   }, handleAuthResult);
}
```

While registering the app, I have been given a `client_secret` which has never been used. Should't `client_secret` be sent out in the `auth_token` request as explained [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization-code-request-response.html) and [here](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified)?

As mentioned in a comment below, I perfectly understand that `client_id` is public as opposed to `client_secret`. What surprises me is, how Google's OAuth 2.0 works in spite of not using `client_secret` to obtain `auth_token`. Isn't that mandated by OAuth 2.0 specification? What is preventing a malicious app to impersonate a legitimate one?

I can set `localhost:8000` as my Javascript origin.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both client id and client secret are used to identify your application.    Client id is public information and is ok to show to users.    While secret must be kept secret or anyone could potently use your application credentials.

JavaScript is client side so if you view source on the page you can see the client id.   If your code also included the secret then they would see that as well and be able to use it.

I suspect that this is the reason we need to use JavaScript orign it adds an extra layer of security instead of using the secret in JavaScript applications.

[RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

> The authorization server issues the registered client a client
> identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
> information provided by the client.  The client identifier is not a
> secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used
> alone for client authentication.  The client identifier is unique to
> the authorization server.

English:  Google developer console registers the application (client) creating a unique string to identifying that client (project).    The client id is not a secrete and should be shown to the owner of the data.

[4.1.  Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)  Client secrete is not a required part of the authorization code exchange as far as I can see.

Comment: I understand that `client_id` is public as opposed to `client_secret`. What surprises me is, how Google's OAuth 2.0 works in spite of not using `client_secret` to obtain `auth_token`. Isn't that mandated by OAuth 2.0 specification?

Comment: What is preventing a malicious app to impersonate a legitimate one?

Comment: Probably some magic inside the JS library would be my guess.   That and the fact that its locked the JavaScript origin and redirect URIs.   Unless the calls are coming from a location you supplied its not going to work.

Comment: I rule out the "magic" part. Security by obscurity will probably never be accepted by the community. A leader will never fall into such trap. 'Location' might be 'the' thing.

Comment: Even I fail to see how 'origin' can add an extra layer of security. During app registration, it happily accepts `location:8000` as the origin.

Comment: I am still digging in the official rfc but it doesn't look like its required for the exchange.   (Pinged someone at Google see if he responds, I am curious to now  )

Comment: Please do let me know if the Google guy responds, I'm finding, too. If I get something, I'll post it here. Still my head is spinning...what exactly prevents a malicious app to "play" my benign app, `client_id` is something that the whole World knows.

Comment: you not setting location:8000 as the origin probably.

Comment: Edited the question, included screenshot

Comment: there is no security issue. client secret is only needed to get a refresh token, which is the only way to get access offline. while the user is present it must aprove the permission, or the browser, by cookies, knows the user already approved. so client secret isnt needed. yes another developer can steal you clientid but it can't use it because the redirect uri wont match.

Comment: It's the restricted origin address (not redirect uri, since there isn't one) that protects your app. In a genuine browser, the Google auth will fail if the app was served from anywhere other than your server. In order to have a malicious app impersonate your app, you would need to persuade the user to run the app using a hacked browser that faked the origin address. Moreover, that user would need to have logged in to his Google account. So there is a risk, but it's minimal. If you haf that level of control, the user is already screwed.

Comment: There is no magic in the libraries, they are simply JavaScript wrappers of the REST API.